# Getting list of messages & pokes in API

Tags: facebook

I've tried using both the old REST API, as well as the Graph API. I can not seem to figure out a way to get a list of ALL messages and pokes (and when I say messages, I mean private messages). These items do not appear in the stream (from what I can tell), so getting them there is not possible. Notification.get() in the REST API only gets unread messages. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Read the basic Graph-mining tutorial at http://ericosgood.com/prog/facebook-android-sdk-tutorial/#comment-216.

To get information about the user, you need to branch /me, for events branch /me/events, for messages you need to branch me/inbox.
Have a look at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/

For pokes use me/pokes.
For both pokes + inbox you'll need the additional permission: read_mailbox.